# Consulta con variable de sesión, ¿no funciona? PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo algunas consultas con PHP y MySQL. ¿Por qué cuando hago una consulta con una variable de sesión no me arroja nada? Lo que quiero es obtener todos los datos y que coincidan con mi variable de sesión que extraigo desde la base de datos de MySQL es un `idaplantel` en la base y en sesión es lo mismo sólo que se agrega de esta forma `$idaplantel`.

Un pequeño ejemplo sería:

```
select * from dprestamo where idplantel = '$idaplantel' <-- variable que inicializo en la sesión de usuario de mi sistema!
```

El `idplantel` es un id que se agrega a la tabla `dprestamo` desde otra tabla que se llama `Cplantel`... y según yo de esta forma si el usuario tiene el `'$idaplantel' =  1` y el `idplantel` es 1 de la tabla `dprestamo` entonces que muestre todo y solo lo que coincida con ese la variable.

Pero no funciona. Tengo una duda sobre el uso de la variable de sesión que estoy usando, ¿qué diferencia tiene esto `$_SESSION['idcaplantel']` y esto `$idcaplantel`? ¿Puede ser eso el problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por el código que has puesto parece que tu consulta esté bien, pero falle la forma de añadir el valor de la variable `$idaplantel` en la consulta.

La forma que tiene PHP de almacenar ciertas variables como las que se almacenan en la sesión o en las peticiones POST y GET es mediante arrays. Puedes ver la documentación sobre el uso del array $_SESSION [aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.session.php).

Tendrías que hacer `$idaplantel = $_SESSION["idaplantel"]` para que funcione la consulta.

Comment: Hola @Galbi creo que ya resolvi el problema pero tengo una duda sobre el uso de la variable de sesion que diferencia tiene esto '".$_SESSION['idcaplantel']."' de esto ----->'$idcaplantel' ? :(

Comment: La forma que tiene PHP de almacenar ciertas variables como las que se almacenan en la sesión o en las peticiones post y get es mediante arrays. Puedes ver la documentación sobre el uso del array $_SESSION [aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.session.php).

Comment: Si al parecer ese era el problema era usar la variable con un array :) muchas gracias @Gilbi

Comment: Por favor no usemos la seccion de respuestas para comentarios. Estos ultimos tiene su seccion correspondiente.

Comment: @KevinDuarte ¿Podrías explicar mejor cuál era el problema (en tu pregunta) y cómo lo resolvió esta respuesta (aquí)? No queda claro y, aunque está como aceptada, la respuesta ha sido marcada para ser eliminada.

Answer (score -1):

Tu código SQL es semánticamente correcto (PERO MUY INSEGURO, ¡¡¡OJO CON LA INYECCIÓN SQL!!!, buscá un tutorial en Google sobre cómo prevenirla)

Pero... ¿Por qué estás tratando $idaplantel como una cadena alfanumérica? Si es un valor numérico, las comillas no van:

```
select * from dprestamo where idplantel = $idaplantel
```

En todo caso, apuesto a que $idaplantel está mal inicializada. En situaciones como esta hacé un echo() de la sentencia SQL que estás ejecutando, y correla en tu cliente SQL de forma manual. El 99% de las veces el error resulta evidente. Apuesto a que si hacés un echo() de esa sentencia justo antes de correrla, te va a salir algo como:

```
select * from dprestamo where idplantel = ''
```

Comment: Por favor no usemos la seccion de respuestas para comentarios. Estos ultimos tiene su seccion correspondiente.